# Last ingredient for the Fiz Beer

Tags: fiz

I can't seem to find the last ingredient. I am missing the "**Key to friendship**" ingredient, got all the other parts.

Answer (score 1):

If you just keep brewing, an old friend will come along and ask you for a favor. He'll hand over the key as thanks.

> Specifically, Eddy will ask you to brew a high quality batch of beer from his *awful* recipe (Quality Cap 0!) to help him get his own brewery dreams off the ground. In thanks, he'll give you the keys to the Bodega.